# String to Decimal not caring decimal point vb.net and silverlight

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, decimal

I have a silverlight app that use a asmx service to pull data in form of a list with object type properties. I have a property called Enviada, when I use the service, this propierty has a value of "12.4521" of string type and when I try to assigne this value to a decimal variable I get 124521 insted of 12.4521, why?

snippet:

```
Dim dcLect As Decimal = R.Enviada '="12.4521"
```

also this fails

```
dclect ="12.4521" 'Output =124521
```

this only happen in the silverlight proyect, when I try on a console app, the conversion works fine.

Comment: `CultureInfo` problem. Specify culture information directly to get consistent behavior no matter what's the current system locale.

Comment: weird, acts like the locale is wrong for Silverlight, using the point as the comma.  what happens if you put in "12,4521"?

Comment: Thanks both, it is the CultureInfo.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by MarcinJuraszek, the problem was the CultureInfo.

I just add

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("es-DO")
```

before convertion and work fine.